# TeamCity "error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "" because it was not found." Does not want to add the file to source control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, teamcity, team-city-10.0

I have a problem with a service application that we build in Team City. The application is dependent on a `application.config` that needs to be copied to the output directory in order for the project to work. However since this file contains sensitive information we don't want this file to exist in source control.

Therefore our first build step is `Create Text File` to add this file to the directory. However we still get the error:

> error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "" because it was not found.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Using: TeamCity Enterprise 10.0.2 (build 42234)

Comment: Did you erase the name of your file from the error message? Elsewise it looks like haven't defined a name for it...

Comment: Please post your file creation and copy code.

Answer (score 0):

It was an error in `Destination file:`

I forgot to add the project after working dir. Working solution:

```
%teamcity.build.workingDir%\SolutionFolder\Project\application.config
```